# when I pass large vector the prod function return inf

Tags: r

## The question is: Find a decimal approximation of the product

[image]

#### This is my logic

```
toThePower<-seq(1,1000, by =1)
numerator <- c(4 * (toThePower^2))
denominator <- c((4 * (toThePower^2)) - 1)
```

when I use prod(numerator) it return inf which i dont want this.

Comment: Wouldn't be prod(numerator/denominator) ?

Comment: There's a fairly low limit to the size of numbers that the floating point format that R uses can support.  It's generally much better to sum the logs of the numbers than to take the product.  At the end (after subtracting the sum of logs of the denominator), use `exp()` to undo the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user2554330 says in comments, in general if you want to compute the ratio of large products, it's best to do the computation on the log scale.

```r
exp(sum(log(numerator))-sum(log(denominator)))
```

Values that are larger than about 1e308 overflow to infinity when using double-precision floating point numbers as R does.  `sum(log10(numerator))` shows that the numerator is about 1e5737 (i.e., 10^(5737)).

`prod(numerator/denominator)` also works (@ViníciusFélix), but the log-sum trick is worth learning - very generally useful.

I haven't thought about it, but I guess this product is supposed to converge to pi/2 ?